# Error en INSERT SQL php

Tags: php, mysql

Al intentar hacer una consulta desde php a una base de datos, recibo este error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 1
```

Se que es algo de `SQL Injection`, pero no logro solucionarlo.
El código php es este:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["tipoUsuario"] != 'P'){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["xmlDocument"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $docFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if ( $_FILES['xmlDocument']['error'] > UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
          header("Location:upload.php");
          exit();
    }else{

        if($docFileType != "xml") {
            $uploadOk = 0;
            echo "Sólo está permitida la subida de archivos XML <br>";
        }

        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["xmlDocument"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<br><br>El archivo ". basename( $_FILES["xmlDocument"]["name"]). " ha sido subido satisfactoriamente. Ahora se procederá a actualizar la BBDD con los datos del archivo.";

                /*

                PARA PERICO: EN ESTE MOMENTO EL ARCHIVO ESTÁ SUBIDO, AHORA PUEDES TRABAJAR CON ÉL. SE ENCUENTRA EN LA VARIABLE $target_file;
                TAL COMO ESTÁ, SE GUARDA UNA COPIA DE TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS SUBIDOS. SI YA EXISTE UNO CON ESE NOMBRE, SE SOBREESCRIBE.

                */
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($target_file);
                   include("conexion.php");
                $mysqli = abrirConexion();

                 $elemento = [
                     "ProductoID" => "",
                     "ProveedorID" => "",
                     "Nombre" => "",
                     "Precio" => "",
                     "Stock" => "",
                     "StockSeguridad" => "",
                     "Color" => "",
                     "Confirmacion" => "",
                     "DadoDeBaja" => "",
                 ];

                   foreach($xml->Producto as $producto){
                       $elemento["ProductoID"] =$producto->ProductoID;
                       $elemento["ProveedorID"] =$_SESSION["ID"];
                       $elemento["Nombre"] =$producto->Nombre;
                       $elemento["Precio"] =$producto->Precio;
                       $elemento["Stock"] =$producto->Stock;
                       $elemento["StockSeguridad"] =$producto->StockSeguridad;
                       $elemento["Color"] =$producto->Color;
                       $elemento["Confirmacion"] =$producto->Confirmacion;
                       $elemento["DadoDeBaja"] =$producto->DadoDeBaja;

                    $sentencia = "SELECT ProductoID FROM productos WHERE ProductoID =" .$elemento["ProductoID"];
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sentencia);

                       if ($result == NULL) { //insert
                           $sentenciaFin = 'INSERT INTO productos(ProveedorID, Nombre, Precio, Stock, StockSeguridad, Color, Confirmacion, DadoDeBaja) VALUES ('
                           . $elemento["ProveedorID"] . ","
                           . '"' .$elemento['Nombre'] . '",'
                           . $elemento['Precio'] . ','
                           . $elemento['Stock'] . ','
                           . $elemento['StockSeguridad'] . ','
                           . '"' .$elemento['Color'] . '",'
                           . '"' .$elemento['Confirmacion'] . '",'
                           . '"' .$elemento['DadoDeBaja'] .'");<br>';

                           if($mysqli->query($sentenciaFin) === TRUE){
                               echo "OLEEE";
                           } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sentenciaFin . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
                        }


                       }else{ //update

                       }
                   }

            } else {
                echo "Lo sentimos, no se ha podido subir el archivo.";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos_pablo.css">
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="subido"><img src="https://freeodoo.com/website/image/product.template/21_7bd0018/image"></div>
        <a href="index.php" class="atras">Atrás</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

El string obtenido de ejecutar este código es:

```
INSERT INTO productos(ProveedorID, Nombre, Precio, Stock, StockSeguridad, Color, Confirmacion, DadoDeBaja) VALUES (0000000004,"Coche5",250000,25,NULL,"Verde oliva","No","No");
```

Sin embargo, si yo copio el `string` que sale de hacer un `echo` y lo pego en la consola de `PHPMyAdmin`, la consulta se resuelve correctamente y me inserta los datos en la Base de Datos. No está mal la sintaxis, es error de `PHP`.

Comment: Tienes un <br> extra al final de tu query.

Comment: Gracias!! Era eso. Escribelo como respuesta para que pueda tickarla como correcta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que tienes un `<br>` extra al final de tu `INSERT`.